# Need Help Uploading django to Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: python, django, droplet

I have all of my files in a folder on digitalocean, but I am currently getting stuck with a *"No module named urls"* Here is what my urls.py and views.py look like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
     return render(request, 'webapp/home.html')
```

html

pretty sure the only line that is wrong in it is

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="{% url 'Displayquest' %}">
```

Comment: Is Django actually installed on your droplet?

Comment: Yes, when you make a droplet you select the ubuntu with django preinstalled.

Comment: What is the actual stack trace and error message?